# How to debug excel VBA COM reference object

Tags: vba, debugging, excel, visual-studio-2013

I created a .Net COM (Component Object Model) DLL, registered it and added it to an Excel VBAProject as a Reference. Now I can call the .Net methods from the VB macros. Is there a way to attach the Visual Studio 2013 debugger to the COM DLL? I tried to attach it to the Excel process but this didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't attach a VS debugger to you COM add-in. Write your log messages to a text file instead.

Comment: Attaching works fine, you have to pick the correct debugger type.  Simpler yet is to automatically start Excel when you press F5.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, "Start external program" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant, you are right. It is enough to change "Attach to" from "Automatic" to "Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code, Native code" and attach to EXCEL process